# Open a new workspace in OSX without using the mouse

Tags: keyboard, applescript, mission-control

I am used to Linux environments but I have to use a Mac for work. Now I am wondering why it seems to be impossible to open new workspaces in OSX without using the mouse? I know how to switch between them or move windows in different workspaces, when they are already open, but there seems no way to open or close a workspace just by keyboard shortcuts. I am already using Amethyst but it seems not to help with this problem. Does anybody know a solution?

I already tried using an AppleScript, that I found in another thread. But it doesn't work since, Mission Control is not available as an application in the current OSX.

```
User
tell application "System Events"
    do shell script "/Applications/Mission\\ Control.app/Contents/MacOS/Mission\\ Control"
    tell process "Dock"
        set countDesktops to count buttons of list 1 of group 1
        --new desktop
        click button 1 of group 1
        --switch to new desktop
        repeat until (count buttons of list 1 of group 1) = (countDesktops + 1)
        end repeat
        click button (countDesktops + 1) of list 1 of group 1
    end tell
end tell
```

I asked ChatGPT to adjust it and this came out:

```
tell application "System Events"
    -- This would be where you'd simulate opening Mission Control, 
    -- but since we can't directly do "Control + Up Arrow", we might consider other methods 
    -- or manual activation before running the script.
    tell process "Dock"
        set countDesktops to count buttons of list 1 of group 1
        -- Assuming Mission Control is already open, attempt to create a new desktop
        click button 1 of group 1
        delay 1 -- Wait for the animation to complete; adjust delay as necessary
        -- Attempt to switch to the new desktop, assuming it's been created
        set newCountDesktops to count buttons of list 1 of group 1
        if newCountDesktops > countDesktops then
            click button newCountDesktops of list 1 of group 1
        end if
    end tell
end tell
```

I saved it as an AppleScript in Automator and assigned a hotkey to it. When I now open mission control manually and press my assigned hotkeys, nothing happens.

How may I debug this?

Comment: Might be easier to create all the Spaces/Desktops you need up front, and the just switch between them.

Comment: How to do it "up front" without using a mouse?

Comment: Enter Mission control and click on the "+" to create all the spaces you might need (up to 16). This needs the mouse, but you only have to do it once.

Comment: this comment doesnt relate to my question. im fully aware that i can use the mouse instead.

Comment: IMHO using the mouse once to create all spaces is easier than creating and debugging a script which does the same (and will only be used a few times).

Comment: Mission Control was removed in Sonoma?

Comment: @MarcWilson The application in /Applications is gone.

Comment: I'm just wondering, is it still in /System/Applications and just no longer faked into /Applications like it was in Monterey and Ventura?

Comment: @MarcWilson Ah right. Knowing this might be enough to get the first script working again.

Answer (score 0):

[Better Touch Tool](https://folivora.ai) (BTT) can be used to do this.

Open the BTT configuration window. Select `Keyboard Shortcuts` from the top dropdown list. There are two plus sign buttons at the bottom of the window, click the rightmost to `Add a New Trigger`. Enter a keyboard shortcut as the `Tigger Name` (mine is `⇧⌃⌥⌘ C`; note that I've mapped the modifiers to the capslock key as a "hyperkey"). Then in the Action Configuration panel, select the `macOS Functionality` section, and then the `Add New Space to Mission Control` action.

This shows my setup:

[image]